# scalamock: Wildcard argument match on subtype

Tags: scala, jmock, scalamock

In my class, I have two versions of a method. One takes an `Exception`, the other a `String`.

```
class Foo {
  def method(e: Exception) = ???
  def method(s: String) = ???
}
```

In `JMock`, I can mock a call to a method based on its type. Notice, I'm using a subtype of `Exception` to be specific about what I'm expecting in my test.

```
context.checking(new Expectations() {{              
    oneOf(mock).method(with(any(SubTypedException.class)));
}}
```

and in `Scalamock`, I can use a wildcard to match

```
(mock.method(_: Exception)).expects(*).once
```

The following doesn't compile when I try to match on a specific subtype (I realise this doesn't make sense in Scala).

```
// doesn't compile    
(mock.method(_: SubTypedException)).expects(*).once
```

How can I convert the `with(any(SubTypesException.class))` in `JMock` to `Scalamock`? I can imagine using a predicate match (`where`), is that the way to go?

> **Edit**: Thinking about it, the JMock `with(any(SubTypedException))` is more about keeping the compiler happy and expressing intent. As I understand it, the `Matcher` is an `IsAnything` matcher so won't actually fail a test if a different type of exception is thrown.
>
> So, it may be asking a bit much of Scalamock to both capture the intent *and* fail the test under the right circumstance. Bonus points in explaining how to do something like `instanceOf` in Scalamock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: The following does not compile, since the type ascription is only to help (static) overloading resolution. The line has nothing specific to Scalamock:

```
(mock.method(_: SubTypedException))
```

To test the runtime type of the argument you can use `ArgThat` which was introduced in ScalaMock `3.2.1` together with a helper function:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def typedArg[T, U : ClassTag]: ArgThat[T] = new ArgThat[T]({
  case x: U => true
  case _ => false
})

(mock.method(_: Exception)).expects(typedArg[Exception, SubTypedException])
```